# Virtual Box VBoxManage: error: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-eth0'

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running virtualbox 4.1 on Debian. If I try to start a VM with a bridged NIC I get this error:

> error: Failed to open/create
>   the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-eth0' (you might need to
>   modprobe vboxnetflt to make it accessible) (VERR_PERMISSION_DENIED).
>   VBoxManage: error: Failed to attach the network LUN
>   (VERR_PERMISSION_DENIED) VBoxManage: error: Details: code
>   NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component Console, interface IConsole,
>   callee

System: Linux localhost.localdomain 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Virtual Box Version: 4.1.18_Debianr78361

The VM starts with a NAT NIC config.

The weirdest thing is if I export this VM and import it to another user, it works. The other user I tested with was the user I usually use for running auto started virtual machines. But I cant remember doing anything special setting this user up. It is only in its own group and no others. I tried to create a new user and import the VM, but I get the same error as above. I've tried purging virtual box, and completely deleting my conf but it does not work. I just cant figure out what the diff is.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to run the VB with the console using **sudo virtualbox** command?

Comment: Also try to install virtualbox-dkmbs package and execute 'modprobe vboxdrv' as root.

Comment: If I just use sudo vboxmanage looks for the VM in roots home dir. I tried logging in as root and importing the VM but I get the same error! So this arbitrary user can do things root cant do somehow. Super odd. I'll try installing that package now.

Comment: Tried this things. No change.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I got the same error on fedora. There was an already configured virtual network, but the VM was trying to bridge on the system network interface. I changed it to point to the virtual network... and it worked. But now I am not sure about the net configuration ... I will post eventually.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to install `virtualbox-4.0` from linux mint. I believe that is actually a downgrade from what in debians repos. Probably packaged different too. Still don't know how the heck I was getting the error I was getting...

```
sudo apt-get install -f virtualbox-4.0
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```